# T-SQL: Update temp table using "from variable" query

Tags: sql, while-loop, sql-server-2012, cursor, sql-update

I have a linked server connecting to a Lotus notes database as the source. The destination will be an MS SQL database.

I have two temp tables.  The first temp table is pulling in the table names from a linked server.  From there, I want to do a record count for each table and store that value into the second temp table beside the table name.

I am having trouble trying to run a loop or cursor for each table name and then updating the second temp table with the record count for each table name.

Right now I am getting an error "Incorrect syntax near 'Execute'".  `SET record_count = Execute(@sqlCommand)`

```
Declare @DB_tables table (
table_cat varchar(1500),
table_schem varchar(1500),
table_name varchar(1500),
table_type varchar(1500),
remarks varchar(1500)
)


Declare @temp_table table (
table_name varchar(1500),
record_count varchar(255),
drop_script varchar(1500),
update_script varchar(1500)
)

--Load Initial data from linked server database
insert into @DB_Tables
exec sp_tables_ex [LINKED_SERVER_DB]

--Load table name from Stored Procedure
INSERT INTO @temp_table (table_name)
SELECT table_name from @DB_Tables 

--select * from @temp_table




--Variable to hold each table name in a loop or cursor
declare @tbl_name varchar(1500)
--declare @sqlCommand varchar(1500)


declare cur cursor for select table_name from @DB_Tables
Open cur

--Loop through each table name from the first temp table
--then update the second temp table (@temp_table) with the record count
FETCH NEXT FROM cur into @tbl_name

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

declare @sqlCommand varchar(1500)
--query used to get the record count from the frist temp table (@DB_tables)
SET @sqlCommand = 'select count(*) from '+@tbl_name

UPDATE @temp_table

SET record_count = Execute(@sqlCommand)

END
CLOSE cur
Deallocate cur



select * from @temp_table
```

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use ?

Comment: SSMS = SQL Server Management Studio is the **management GUI** application - not the actual **database system** - this *might* be SQL Server 2012 - or it might be a different version (since the Management GUI doesn't have to be identical in terms of its version to the underlying SQL Server **core engine**)

Comment: I have a linked server connecting to a Lotus notes database as the source. The destination will be an MS SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to use table variables with execute because the dynamic SQL is executed in the different context and doesn't see the variable and you can't assign results from execute that way.

You can either insert the results into a table variable with this syntax:

```
insert into @temp_table 
execute ('select ' + @tbl_name + ', count(*) from ' + @tbl_name ...)
```

Or use temp. tables, since then you can refer them also inside the dynamic SQL, so you could do something like:

```
create table #temp_table  (
table_name varchar(1500),
record_count varchar(255),
drop_script varchar(1500),
update_script varchar(1500)
)
...
Execute('update #temp_table set record_count = (select count(*) from '
        +@tbl_name+') where table_name = '''+@tbl_name+''')
```